# Powerset of $ \mathbb N $ and the continuum $\mathfrak c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$ 2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak c$ is a theorem of ZFC, without involvement of the Continuum Hypothesis.

Under what assumptions would this equality fail?

Obviously, at least the infinity axiom and the existence of powerset for sets of size $ \aleph_0 $ would need to hold. Do these suffice to force the equality?

Comment: You need at least some comprehension, and some scaffolding allowing you to define functions (the latter can be accomplished in several ways, you can choose here). Comprehension is used so that you can actually define the obvious bijection: Given a function from $\mathbb N$ to $2$, you want to argue that there the obvious corresponding subset of $\mathbb N$ is indeed a set.

Comment: How are you defining $\mathfrak c$?  Usually I think of $2^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak c$ or something equivalent as the definition, so it cannot fail.  You are correct that you need infinity and powerset to show that the definition makes sense.

Comment: $\mathfrak{c}$ is the cardinality of the reals by definition. So you need to be able to define the reals, which needs quite a bit of ZFC.